# Empty string checking issue: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Checking if value of element is greater then or equal to Zero(0) but in case of empty string its result true

```
    var amount = $(this).text();
    if (amount >= 0) {
        $(this).text(parseInt(amount).toLocaleString());
    }
```

if `amount = ""` then result is `NaN` why?

Comment: Type coercion makes `'0' == 0 // true`.

Comment: Empty string `""` coerces to `0` here.

Answer (score 2):

Yes .because `amount` is a string on the time  of validation .Empty `space` also have length

`"" == 0`

**Error**

```js
var amount=""
console.log(amount >=0)
```

**FIX**

Try to validate simple `if(var)` .Use `trim()` remove unwanted empty spaces

```
var amount = $(this).text().trim();
    if (amount) {
        $(this).text(parseInt(amount).toLocaleString());
    }
```